# onmouseout behavior in js and html

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseout

```
<a href="/somewhere" onmouseout="someFunction()">blah blah blah<img src="blah.jpg"></a>
```

In the above link, I have `someFunction()` firing when the mouse leaves the link. Seems straight forward. But when I hover over the image 'blah.jpg' the onmouseout event also fires. This is not desirable because 'blah.jpg' is in fact in the `a` node. The same thing happens if i have a div inside the `a` node, or any other html element other than straight text: javascript considers this to be *out* of the `a` node. Is there a way to stop these events from improperly firing?  The described behavior is in chrome and ff on win7.

*update: if there is a jquery solution, do tell

Comment: Sounds like you might want `onmouseup` instead...

Comment: Why would click-related event like `mouseup` help the OP when he's trying to use `mouseout`?

Comment: Perhaps evaluate whether the `mouseout` is triggered by moving to a `childNode`? I'm not sure exactly how, though, in plain JavaScript.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It wouldn't if mouseout is really needed but can't the image be moved outside the <a /> tag? I might be missing something but isn't this the desirable behaviour?

Comment: If the image still needs to be clickable, what about putting both inside different <a /> tags and having the onmouseout only on the text?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you closed your img tag properly: <img src="blah.jpg"/>

Comment: @DanS my total desired effect is to have the onmouseout event fire only  when the mouse leaves the `a` node and all it's children. Currently it is firing when it hovers over childNodes inside the a node. Not sure how your solution accomplishes this, perhaps I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar in concept to shehzad, so I voted him up. Should work cross-browser.
in html:

```
onmouseout='out(this)'
```

in js (with included jquery file):

```
out(thisRef) {
   var newHover = event.relatedTarget || event.toElement;
   if(!jQuery.contains(thisRef,newHover) && !(thisRef==newHover)) {
        someFunction();
   }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by verifying the the node type. Try

```
onmouseout="if ((event.relatedTarget || event.toElement) == this.parentNode) someFunction()"
```

Comment: This will most likely work, but should really go in it's own handler. Having it in an `on-` attribute gives me nightmares.

Comment: Also, that's is definitely not cross-browser.